# vertical align in pseudo-element with absolute position

Tags: html, css

I have a "button" element that must be horizontally centered, I did it with 
`margin: 0 auto;` 
But right next to that button I have empty by default `:after` pseudo-element which will contain text depending on server response.

Right now it works like this:

```css
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.button:after {
  cursor: default;
  text-align: left;
  content:'response text here';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -180px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="button">click me!</div>
</div>
```

And works fine, but if that response text contains 2 lines (which may happen) the second line will not fit vertically because of `line-height` parameter.
So the question is: how do I vertically center response text in this situation?

If I make `:after` element `display:table-cell` it will not work because of `position:absolute`, flexbox to `.button` will also affect button text.
Another solution that comes to my mind is made 2 `<dv>` in a row, but if so I don't know how to position them like that.

Comment: Are there any elements surrounding your button element?

Comment: no, parent div is same with as whole form div (600px approx), and so button only surrounded by white space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset the `line-height` to `normal` or so on the absolute positioned pseudo element, and use `top: 50%` + `transform: translateY(-50%)` to center it vertically.

I also suggest to use `left: 100%` rather than `right: -180px`, so that it works with dynamic button width.

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 36px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 170px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: normal;
  cursor: default;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="button" data-text="response text here">click me!</div>
  <div class="button" data-text="response text response text here">click me!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanx! I prefer this solution cause flex seems bugged with IE11 while I don't even care about Opera Mini.

Answer (score 2):

You can try flex and no need to specify line-height:

```css
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 36px;
  margin:10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.button:after {
  cursor: default;
  text-align: left;
  content:attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -180px;
  bottom:0;
  width: 170px; 
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="button" data-text="response text here">click me!</div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="button" data-text="response text here response text">click me!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the position of the pseudo-element with a `transform` to center it vertically.

Use flexbox to align the button text rather than `line-height` which would be inherited.

```css
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 36px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1em
}

.button:after {
  cursor: default;
  content: 'response text goes here and here here';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="button">click me!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add a container div like this:

```
<div class="center">
  <div class="button">click me!</div>
</div>
```

and in CSS:

```
.center {
  margin: 50% auto;
  width: 370px;
}
```